# Using terminal-kit package in debug mode | WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm trying to debug code(Shift+F9) in Webstorm, and I got error "Error: Terminal is not capable"

```
var term = require( 'terminal-kit' ).terminal ;

var history = [ 'John' , 'Jack' , 'Joey' , 'Billy' , 'Bob' ] ;

var autoComplete = [
    'Barack Obama' , 'George W. Bush' , 'Bill Clinton' , 'George Bush' ,
    'Ronald W. Reagan' , 'Jimmy Carter' , 'Gerald Ford' , 'Richard Nixon' ,
    'Lyndon Johnson' , 'John F. Kennedy' , 'Dwight Eisenhower' ,
    'Harry Truman' , 'Franklin Roosevelt'
] ;

term( 'Please enter your name: ' ) ;

var input = await term.inputField(
    { history: history , autoComplete: autoComplete , autoCompleteMenu: true }
).promise ;

term.green( "\nYour name is '%s'\n" , input ) ;
process.exit()
```

When I run the same code in terminal everything is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails with `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` for me... anyway, I suppose that the error occurs because  Node console in WebStorm is non-Tty, as node process is started with input/output streams redirection.
You can work out the issue by enabling using terminal console for Node.js. To do this, please try the following:

- choose **Help | Find Action...** on the main menu;
- type `registry` to locate the **Registry**
- find `nodejs.console.use.terminal` key there and enable it.

[image]

This should do the thing

The key is available in all IDEs since 2018.2, but you need to have **Node.js** plugin installed

Comment: Thanks, it works for WebStorm. Did you know PphpStorm has this feature? I can't find it in PhpStorm

Comment: it's there - I've updated my answer with screenshot taken in Phpstorm. But you need to make sure to install and enable *Node.js* plugin